# Select device to play MIDI using pygame.mixer.music

Tags: python, pygame, midi

I'm using `pygame.mixer.music` to play back some MIDI files from my Python application. I'd like to give the user the option to select the MIDI device to send the output to. This works fine when using `pygame.midi.Output` to play back single events, but I cannot find any way to select the `device_id` to use for `pygame.mixer.music`.

How do I set the output device that `pygame.mixer.music` uses to play MIDI files?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the device with [`pygame.mixer.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init) or [`pygame.mixer.pre_init`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init):

> ```
> init(frequency=44100, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=512, devicename=None,
>      allowedchanges=AUDIO_ALLOW_FREQUENCY_CHANGE | AUDIO_ALLOW_CHANNELS_CHANGE) -> None
> ```

> ```
> pre_init(frequency=44100, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=512, devicename=None) -> None
> ```